# sql statement combine counting 2 statements results

Tags: sql-server

I'm having trouble with combining the 2 statements.

I have a `festivalTable` which you can vote on => `voteTable`. and for special occasions you can also have a `specialVoteTable`

for the 2 seperate tables i have:

```
select festivalId as festId, COUNT(festivalId) as total from Vote 
where active = 'J'  and FestivalId = 593
group by FestivalId
```

the same for the other table. Now I need to combine these 2 results, with the exception that from the specialvote i need to multiply it by 8, so i can devide the total by 9.

so the 2 seperate queries are

```
select festivalId as festId, COUNT(festivalId) as total from Vote 
where active = 'J'  and FestivalId = 593
group by FestivalId

select festivalId as festId, (COUNT(festivalId) * 8) as total from       SpecialChartVote 
where active = 'J'  and FestivalId = 593
group by FestivalId
```

(not combined with the `festivalTable` yet.)

Makes any sense?

Answer (score 2):

using `union all` in a subquery:

```
select festId, sum(total)/9 as total
from 
  (
  select 
      festivalId as festId
    , COUNT(festivalId) as total 
  from Vote 
  where active = 'J'  and FestivalId = 593
  group by FestivalId
  union all 
  select 
      festivalId as festId
    , (COUNT(festivalId) * 8) as total 
  from SpecialChartVote 
  where active = 'J'  and FestivalId = 593
  group by FestivalId
  ) u
group by festId
```

Comment: You never divided the total by 9.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated. I wasn't sure if he wanted to divide it by 9 in the same query, or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your query, as written, is only looking for one festival.  That seems strange, but you can combine the queries by doing:

```
select 593 as festId,
       ( (select count(*) from Vote where active = 'J'  and FestivalId = 593) +
         (select count(*) * 8 from SpecialChartVote where active = 'J' and FestivalId = 593)
       ) / 9.0
```

SQLZims answer is definitely better if you want to get the information for multiple festivals.  I just want to point you that you can "combine" your queries essentially by doing:

```
select (<query1> + <query2>)
```